# Highlight row if column A has ONLY 1 matching variable in column B

Tags: excel

I literally don't know how to ask this.

I have two columns, column A list customer sites (data changed to states).
Column B has all the technicians who have serviced that site (data changed to random names).

I want to highlight all rows if a site was only serviced by the same technician.

[image: Picture of table]

In the attached example, I would want to highlight Nevada and Tennessee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Conditional Format with the following formula:

```
=AND(ROW($A1)<> 1,COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,"<>"&$B1)=0,$A1<>"")
```

And apply it to: $A:$B

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct. Thank you so much @Scott Craner. I have been stuck on this all day!